# How to have multiple y axis with different color in chart.js react

Tags: reactjs, charts, chart.js, react-chartjs, react-chartjs-2

Here is my component. i really appreciate your help.

```
...
export interface AreaChartProps {
  data: {
    data: {
      x: string;
      y: number;
    }[];
    fill?: boolean;
    borderColor?: string;
    backgroundColor?: string;
    label?: string;
    pointRadius?: number;
    pointBackgroundColor?: string;
  }[];
  labels: string[];
  options?: any;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
  title?: string;
}

function AreaChart({
  data,
  labels,
  options: customOptions,
  style,
  title,
}: AreaChartProps) {
  const [sliderValues, setSliderValues] = useState([0, labels.length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSliderValues([0, labels.length]);
  }, [labels]);

  const datasets = {
    labels: labels.slice(sliderValues[0], sliderValues[1]),
    datasets: data.map((dataset, index) => ({
      ...dataset,
      yAxisID: dataset.label,
      data: dataset.data.filter(
        (data_) =>
          !labels.slice(0, sliderValues[0]).includes(data_.x) &&
          !labels.slice(sliderValues[1]).includes(data_.x)
      ),
    })),
  };

  const onSliderChange = (values: number[]) => {
    setSliderValues(values);
  };

  const options: any = {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        intersect: false,
      },
      legend: {
        position: 'top',
      },
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: title,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      y: data.map((item, index) => ({
        type: 'linear',
        display: false,
        position: index % 2 === 0 ? 'right' : 'right',
        id: item.label,
        beginAtZero: true,
        grace: '10%',
        ticks: {
          color: item.borderColor, // Set the color of the y-axis to match the border color of the dataset
          borderColor: item.borderColor,
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'red', // Set the color of the y-axis to match the border color of the dataset
          borderColor: 'red',
        },
      })),
    },
    tension: 0.3,
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ ...style }}>
      <Line
        key={JSON.stringify(datasets)}
        options={{ ...options, ...customOptions }}
        data={{
          labels: datasets.labels,
          datasets: datasets.datasets,
        }}
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          maxWidth: '100%',
          maxHeight: '100%',
          // height: '535px',
          // maxHeight: '440px',
          ...style,
        }}
      />
      <Slider
        range
        min={0}
        max={labels.length}
        value={sliderValues}
        onChange={onSliderChange as any}
        className='mx-auto w-[90%]'
        style={{
          marginTop: '1rem',
          maxWidth: '96%',
          marginInline: 'auto',
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AreaChart;
```

In this component, i want to have multiple axis with different colors but it is not happening. I searched so much but could not find the answer. The most interesting part is that even if i comment out the following options, y axis are still showing without any change.

```
y: data.map((item, index) => ({
        type: 'linear',
        display: false,
        position: index % 2 === 0 ? 'right' : 'right',
        id: item.label,
        beginAtZero: true,
        grace: '10%',
        ticks: {
          color: item.borderColor, // Set the color of the y-axis to match the border color of the dataset
          borderColor: item.borderColor,
        },
        grid: {
          color: 'red', // Set the color of the y-axis to match the border color of the dataset
          borderColor: 'red',
        },
      })),
```

Comment: With "y: data.map((item, index) =>" you are reporting an array for Y axis definition and that's wrong. In scales option, you should have a key (scale id) and an object (scale config).